# Hoe to modify a current active tab url using c++

Tags: c++, url, browser, tabs

I currently have a C++ program written using QT and would like to simulate opening a tab then then changing the tab url then executing the url again (without having to open another tab) and so on.

For example:

1. Open https://www.n11.com/magaza/blcfiltre?pg=1 in firefox.
2. change current active tab to https://www.n11.com/magaza/blcfiltre?pg=2 and execute it.
3. change current active tab to https://www.n11.com/magaza/blcfiltre?pg=3 and execute it.
   and so forth.

Is it possible to do it using c++ (or not because it is an external browser) and how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you really trying to do and why do you think Qt is the best solution?

Comment: I did not say QT is the best solution. I am stating the current status of my app. I just want to know if this could be achieved using c++ or not.

Comment: If all you want to do is drive a (headless) web browser, why not use selenium or the webdriver plugin for your favorite browser engine? Although I fail to see what you stand to gain by using c++ for that.

Comment: I am now trying to use WebDriver. I will post solution if it works. Thanks.